# Simplify two inductive proofs with the same inductive step but different base case.

Tags: proof-writing, induction

So I was reading a proof with this inductive part which proves that sin(n*π)=0 for all nonegative integers and I noticed that for both cases the inductive step is the same although they have different base cases. Is there a nice way to simplify the proof and only use the inductive step once?

[image]

Comment: Well, it's true for $n=1$ and $\sin((n+1)\pi)=\sin(n\pi)\cos(\pi)+\sin(\pi)\cos(n\pi)=0+0=0$

Comment: @lulu Thanks, that would work, but I would still like a way to do it with two base cases, just in case I ever need it again.

Comment: I don't understand.  The method you provided uses two base cases, namely $0,1$ (or $2,1$ if you prefer).

Comment: @lulu I know, it's just that I wondered whether it would be possible to merge the two proofs so that I could make the inductive step in the example just once. In this case, your suggestion would work better, but the example I made was just a general doubt I have about proofs with various base cases but just one inductive step.